# Can you insert data from excel files on a sharepoint into an sql azure db using logic apps?

Tags: excel, azure-logic-apps

I am quite new to logic apps and I am stuck.

I have a sharepoint where people will be uploading their excel file with targets (all have the same format). I want to be able to load the data from these excel files into an azure sql table with logic apps. The issue here is that I need to loop over all the excel files, but it doesn't know the column names of the file.
Is it possible to do this with logic apps?

Greetings

Comment: If you don't know the column names of the file, how will you map those columns into your Azure SQL Database? If you have any existing code please post it. This might be achieved more easily with PowerApps